# Assembly Binding Redirect not working for ChilkatDotNet2

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've attempting to upgrade chilkat 9.0.8.0 to 9.5.0 using a binding redirect. I dont have access to the un-compiled source for this dll that is referencing it as its a 3rd party app, and the creator isn't answering emails.

Below is my web.config, its a DNN 5.6.3 installation so there is other binding redirects in there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;" />
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ChilkatDotNet2" publicKeyToken="eb5fc1fc52ef09bd">
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.5.0.0" newVersion="9.5.0.45" />
                </assemblyIdentity>
            </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2011.1.519.35" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
```

I've also tried putting this in the machine.config as well, below is the machine config (in the framework64 folder as im running 64bit)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ChilkatDotNet2" publicKeyToken="eb5fc1fc52ef09bd">
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.5.0.0" newVersion="9.5.0.45" />
        </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I've used fuslogvw.exe and below is the logs i get from it regarding the binding mismatch error (after the above has been applied)

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (30/11/2014 @ 1:04:08 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = DC1VS-APP05\AppPool_w1001Bulk
LOG: DisplayName = ChilkatDotNet2, Version=9.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09bd
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/SITES/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\SITES\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = T:\TEMPASPNET\root\6a956f13
LOG: Cache Base = T:\TEMPASPNET\root\6a956f13
LOG: AppName = 94415c18
Calling assembly : EmailManager, Version=2.70.1.23540, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\SITES\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: ChilkatDotNet2, Version=9.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09bd
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///T:/TEMPASPNET/root/6a956f13/94415c18/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///T:/TEMPASPNET/root/6a956f13/94415c18/ChilkatDotNet2/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/SITES/bin/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: E:\SITES\bin\ChilkatDotNet2.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: ChilkatDotNet2, Version=9.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09bd
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Joel